# How to best implement a partition function for iterables?

Tags: dart

I have grown quite fond of dart's list-operating functions. However, I often find myself in the situation of needing a "partition" function, where a list is split into two parts according to a boolean criteria. Meaning, the same as the `.where`, but which doesn't discard the false ones.

Obvious implementation:

```dart
Iterable partition(Iterable list, filter) {
  var matches    = [];
  var nonMatches = [];
  list.forEach((e) {
    if (filter(e)) {
      matches.add(e);
    } else {
      nonMatches.add(e);
    }
  });
  return [matches, nonMatches];
}
```

However, I have also grown fond of the lazy iterables which `where` is returning.

Another implementation would be to use sets:

```dart
Iterable partition(Iterable list, filter) {
  var matches    = list.where(filter);
  var nonMatches = list.toSet().difference(matches.toSet()).toList();
  return [matches, nonMatches];
}
```

I would be happy to see how an elegant lazy implementation could be done (if it is easy).
I believe that construction a set from a list is an `O(n)` operation, so the two implementations shouldn't be too different in efficiency. Comments wanted on that.

**Update**
The set implementation is flawed. I don't exactly see why it doesn't work, but the `nonMatches` does not contain all the numbers not contained in `matches`.

Comment: I did some benchmarking. The construction of a set was much slower than I anticipated, and the `forEach` implementation seemed to be roughly 90% faster for splitting a randomly generated int-dataset of 100 000.

Comment: I think the first implementation is perfectly fine. If you really want to be lazy, it will be much more complicated. You would return two custom iterables that share a single iterator on the original iterable, and which builds the underlying lists incrementally when you advance an iteration of either of the returned iterables past the lists built so far. Doable, but pretty certainly not worth the effort.

Comment: @lrn  "We Need To Go Deeper" Overload all access methods and generate collection elements on direct access.  Make virtual collection. :P

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```dart
Iterable partition(Iterable list, filter) {
  return [list.where((e) => filter(e)), list.where((e) => !filter(e))];
}
```

Regards
Robert

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but there is two iterations, and for the cases where filter is expensive to compute, you don't want to do it twice.

Answer (score 2):

You can seamlessly mix it in to the view, for example `UnmodifiableListView`:

```dart
import "package:unittest/unittest.dart";
import "dart:collection";

class Tuple<A,B> {
  final A a;
  final B b;
  const Tuple(this.a, this.b);
  String toString() {
    return "(a: $a, b : $b)";
  }
}

abstract class  partitionMixin<RES, E>{
  Iterable<E> where(bool test(E element));
  Map<E, bool> _filterCache = new Map();
  Tuple<RES,RES> partition(bool filter(E e)) {
    bool cachedFilter(E e) {
      if (_filterCache.containsKey(e)) return _filterCache[e];
      else {
        bool filterRes = filter(e);
        _filterCache[e] = filterRes;
        return filterRes;
      }
    }
    return new Tuple(this.where(cachedFilter),
        this.where((E e) => !cachedFilter(e)));
  }
}


 class  ExtULV<E> = UnmodifiableListView<E> with
                              partitionMixin<ExtULV<E>,E>;

void main() {

  test('Split one iterable in two"', () {

    var foo = (e) => (e % 2) == 0;
    var fooA =  [2,4,6,8, 10, 12, 14];
    var fooB =  [1,3,5,7,9,11,13];
    var fooRes = new Tuple(fooA, fooB);

    var tested = new ExtULV([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14]);
    var testRes = tested.partition(foo);
    print("fooRes : $fooRes\ntestRes: $testRes");
    expect(testRes.a.toList().toString() == fooRes.a.toString(), true);
    expect(testRes.b.toList().toString() == fooRes.b.toString(), true);

  });
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution with the cache. I get an error that ExtULV complains that it cant accept a reference to itself. Works nicely just to drop the type specification for partitionMixin, like `class ExtULV<E> = UnmodifiableListView<E> with partitionMixin;`

Comment: @tusj Thanks for the feedback! Type annotation is optional so you can drop it. I'm using 1.5.0.dev SDK,  might be this is why i don't have this problem.

Comment: I have done some more benchmarking. The cache beats the forEach for sufficiently tough comparisons. (Used a recursive fibonacci as example).

Answer (score 1):

If you generalize it it gets simpler

```
  Map groupedBy(f, list) {
    var grouped = {};
    for (var thing in list) {
      grouped.putIfAbsent(f(thing), () => []).add(thing);  
    }
   return grouped;
  }
```

though it's not so easy to make it lazy.

Answer (score 1):

Dart version:

```
$ dart --version
Dart SDK version: 3.1.3 (stable) (Tue Sep 26 14:25:13 2023 +0000) on "linux_x64"
```

partition function:

```
(List, List) partition<T>(Iterable<T> iter, bool Function(T) pred) {
  return iter.fold(([], []), (res, item) {
    var (l1, l2) = res; // bc cannot pattern match on func params without type annotations
    switch (pred(item)) {
      case true:  l1.add(item);
      case false: l2.add(item);
    }
    return (l1, l2);
  });
}

partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], (n) => n.isEven); // ([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7])
```

As an extension on Iterables:

```
extension PartIterable on Iterable {
  (List, List) partition<T>(bool Function(T) pred) {
    return fold(([], []), (res, item) {
      var (l1, l2) = res;
      switch (pred(item)) {
        case true:  l1.add(item);
        case false: l2.add(item);
      }
      return (l1, l2);
    });
  }
}

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7].partition((int n) => n.isEven); // ([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7])
```

What does it mean to be lazy regarding the return value of two lists? The question doesn't make a lot of sense. Principally you could implement an Iterable which are lazily evaluated. But what would you return?

```
void main(List<String> arguments) {
  var part = Partition([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], (n) => n.isEven);
  for (final item in part) {
    print(item);
  }
}

class Partition<T> extends Iterable<(List<T>, List<T>)> {
  List<T> inputList;
  bool Function(T) pred;
  Partition(this.inputList, this.pred);

  @override
  Iterator<(List<T>, List<T>)> get iterator =>
      PartitionIterator(inputList, pred);
}

class PartitionIterator<T> implements Iterator<(List<T>, List<T>)> {
  int index = 0;
  bool Function(T) pred;
  List<T> inputList;
  List<T> left = [];
  List<T> right = [];

  PartitionIterator(this.inputList, this.pred);

  @override
  get current => (left, right); // what to return here ???

  @override
  bool moveNext() {
    switch (index >= inputList.length) {
      case true:
        return false;
      case false:
        final item = (inputList[index]);
        switch (pred(item)) {
          case true:
            left.add(item);
          case false:
            right.add(item);
        }
        index++;
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

main's output:

```
([], [1])
([2], [1])
([2], [1, 3])
([2, 4], [1, 3])
([2, 4], [1, 3, 5])
([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5])
([2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5, 7])
```